# Error: In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r

I'm new to R, but I'm trying to estimate a missing value in a large microarray dataset using `impute.knn()` from library(impute) using 6 nearest neighbors.

Here's an example:

```
seq1 <- seq(1:12)
mat1 <- matrix(seq1, 3)
mat1[2,2] <- "NA"
impute.knn(mat1, k=6)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in knnimp.internal(x, k, imiss, irmiss, p, n, maxp = maxp) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I've also tried the following:

```
impute.knn(mat1[2,2], k=6)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in rep(1, p) : invalid 'times' argument
```

My google-fu has been off today. Any suggestions to why I might be getting this error?

edit: I've tried

```
mat1[2,2] <- NA
```

as James suggested, but I get a segmentation fault. Using

```
replace(mat1, mat1[2,2], NA)
```

does not help either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Without a reproducible example it could be lots of things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What package are you using that contains `impute.knn`?

Comment: I suspect that the line `mat1[2,2] <- "NA"` is to blame. `"NA"` is a character string, try using `NA`.

Comment: ...and because `"NA"` is a character, it's changing the entire `mat1` to a character matrix. This causes an error when you try `storage.mode(mat1)<-"double"`

Comment: I tried not putting the quotes around NA, but then I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @James, I'm using library(impute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why `impute.knn` is set up the way it is, but the example within `?impute.knn` uses `khanmiss` which is a `data.frame` of factors, which when coerced to `matrix` will be character.

You are getting a segmentation fault because you are trying to impute with  `K > ncol(mat1)` nearest neighbours. It might be worth reported a bug to the package authors, as this could easily be checked in `R` and return an error, not a `C` level error which kills R.

```
mat1 <- matrix(as.character(1:12), 3)
mat1[2,2] <- NA # must not be quoted for it to be a NA value
# mat1 is a 4 column matrix so
impute.knn(mat1, 1)
impute.knn(mat1, 2)
impute.knn(mat1, 3)
impute.knn(mat1, 4)
# Will all work
```

## note

despite the strange example, `mat1`will when it is integer or double as well

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:12,3)
mat1[2,2] <- NA
impute.knn(mat1,2)

mat1 <- matrix(seq(0,1,12),3)
mat1[2,2] <- NA
impute.knn(mat1,2)
```

## take home message

Don't try to use impute using more information than you have.

Perhaps the package authors should take heed of

```
fortunes(15)
```

> It really is hard to anticipate just how silly users can be. —Brian D.
>   Ripley R-devel (October 2003)

and build in some error checking so a simple error does not cause a segfault.

Comment: I tried this on my dataset, but when I try to get the dimensions via dim(matrix), NULL is returned. Have any idea why?

Comment: If you post your data, then I could answer your question. If your data is called *my_data*, post the results of *dput(head(my_data))*

Comment: I ended up posting my problem here as I cannot share code in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774318/matrix-turns-into-something-else-when-i-run-it-through-impute-knn