# Matrix turns into something else when I run it through impute.knn.

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R, but I have a microarray dataset. I have an NA value at one location, and I try to use impute.knn() from library(impute), but after running the matrix through the impute.knn() function, it seems to turn into another structure. Can anyone explain what's going on?

```
> m <- as.matrix(m)

# checking structure
> str(m)
  num [1:22283, 1:20] 1942.1 40.1 72.1 4693.6 35.9 ...
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:22283] "1007_s_at" "1053_at" "117_at" "121_at" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:20] "GSM146778-Normal" "GSM146780-Normal" "GSM146782-Normal"

# checking missing value of cell
> m[x,y] 
[1] NA

# impute missing value
> m.i <- impute.knn(m, 6)

# check value of imputed value
> m.i[x,y]
Error in r.imp["206054_at", "GSM146784-Normal"] : incorrect number of dimensions

# check structure of imputed matrix
> str(m.i)
List of 3
$ data     : num [1:22283, 1:20] 1942.1 40.1 72.1 4693.6 35.9 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:22283] "1007_s_at" "1053_at" "117_at" "121_at" ...
.. ..$ : chr [1:20] "GSM146778-Normal" "GSM146780-Normal" "GSM146782-Normal" "GSM146784-Normal" ...
$ rng.seed : num 3.62e+08
$ rng.state: int [1:626] 403 50 1992223309 -108730617 1600482030 698744776
```

Comment: What is `x`, what is `y`? Please post a reproducible example! - including (a subset) of your data

Comment: @mnel, x and y were the row/column names. James explained that you can call the matrix with the '$' character, so I got what I needed. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Glad to hear you've got your problem solved, but it is still good practice to post reproducible examples (as you did in your other question)

Comment: I apologize, I will keep that in mind. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @SteveHwang It is also useful to accept answers if they help you ;)

Comment: @James What does that mean? Are you referring to the up arrow? I cannot promote it because I don't have 15 reputation points yet.

Comment: @SteveHwang No, the green tick. It rewards the answerer and shows other users that the problem has been solved. I see you have done this now though, thank you.

Comment: I figured that was what you were inferring. Appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `impute.knn` function returns a list which contains the matrix and other data regarding the imputation. Try using:

```
m.i$data[x,y]
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could call those variables. This will be very valuable in the future. One more question: Is there any way to save the data? When I try > m.i <- as.matrix(m.i$data), I get an error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: `m.i$data` is the matrix. As you are overwriting, are you sure you haven't already called this and now `m.i` is no longer the list?